# Determining Which Areas Under Curves Are Equal

Tags: integration

I have the following question from my calculus 2 homework and I'm really stumped:

> Three regions have areas $A$, $B$, $C$
>
> The grey area $A$ is the area of a region bounded by the graph of the function $f(x) = \ln x$ and the $x$-axis over the interval $x \in[1, e]$.
>
> The green area $B$ is the area of a region bounded by the graph of the function $f(x) = e^{\sin x}\sin 2x$ and the $x$-axis over the interval $x \in [0, \pi/2]$.
>
> The orange area $C$ is the area of a region bounded by the graph of the function $f(x) = xe^x$ and the $x$-axis over the interval $x \in [0, 1]$.
>
> Two of the three areas $A$, $B$, and $C$ are actually equal. Find out which areas are equal. Do not forget to write down the correct mathematical solution to this problem!

So far, all I've been able to do is setup the areas as integrals:

$A = \int_1^e\ln x\ dx$

$B = \int_0^{\pi/2}e^{\sin x}\sin2x\ dx$

$C = \int_0^1xe^x dx$

I'm thinking that in order to show a mathematical solution to the question, I have to solve or at least simplify the integrals. Here's where the problem lies.

I have no idea how to solve these. For example, for the area of $A$, it seems that I have to use integration by parts to solve it but we haven't been taught how to do that yet (I know for sure that we are not expected to read ahead). So far, we've only done basic substitution. So now I wonder, is there another way to solve these without using integration by parts?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Try making the substitution $u=\ln x$ in $A$, and consider the form of the resulting definite integral.

Answer (score 0):

Hints (for you to check):

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;\;\;\int\log x\,dx=x\log x-x+K\;,\;\;K=\text{ constant}\\
\bullet&\;\;\;\;\;\int e^{\sin x}\sin2x\,dx=2\int e^{\sin x}\sin x\cos x\,dx=2\sin xe^{\sin x}-2\int e^{\sin x}\cos x\,dx\\
\bullet&\;\;\;\;\int xe^xdx=xe^x-\int e^xdx\end{align*}$$

BTW, all three integrals above are quickly solved by means of integration by parts. The second one only requires a basic trigonometric identity.